# Join with table

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

Say I have two tables as below where Table A has columns name and type where each name may appear many times and with different type and Table B has unique code, name and sum.

Table A

```
John  Type1  
Mark  Type2  
John  Type1  
Mark  Type3  
John  Type4  
Paul  Type5
```

Table B

```
1  John  20  
2  Mark  33   
3  Paul  22  
4  Mark  55  
5  John  46
```

Now what I want is something like this:

Table C

```
1  John  20  Type1  
2  Mark  33  Type2  
3  Paul  22 Type5  
4 Mark 55 Type2  
5 John 46 Type1
```

Normally Table A should contain unique entries with one type for each name and I could do a right join Table B on name to get what I want. But now if I do right join I get duplicate entries on Table C because name has duplicates types in Table A. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
WITH TableAA
AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME,TYPE) RN
  ,name
  ,type
  FROM TableA
)

SELECT 
B.*
,(
  SELECT type from TableAA A WHERE A.name= B.name AND A.RN=
  ISNULL(NULLIF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TableB C WHERE C.NAME=B.name 
          and C.no < B.no),0),1)
  ) AS Type 

FROM   
TableB B
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c77fd/27)**

Comment: great. could you please explain briefly the logic behind this? thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
SELECT A.*,B.TYPE  
  FROM dbo.TABLE_2  A RIGHT JOIN  
(
  SELECT DISTINCT(NAME),MIN(TYPE)TYPE 
    FROM TABLE_1 
   GROUP BY NAME
) B ON A.NAME=B.NAME 
 ORDER BY CODE ASC
```

TABLE_1= TABLE A 
TABLE_2= TABLE B

Comment: the use of MIN does magic. I had very similar code without MIN and it wasn't working but using MIN seems to be the answer.